# How to use CATextLayer together with NSMutableAttributedString

Tags: ios, core-animation, core-text, catextlayer

I try to use a **CATextLayer** together with a **NSMutableAttributedString**.

Once I set the string property of my CATextLayer to an NSMutableAttributedString it gets automatically replaced by an immutable NSAttributedString.

I checked for the result of calling **class** on the string property before and after setting it and the pointer.
I hand an **NSConcreteMutableAttributedString** to the CoreTextLayer and right after the setter is called and I ask the CATextLayer for the class of its string property, I get this result: **NSConcreteAttributedString**. Also the pointers are different before and after (obviously).

What can I do to get that right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with what's happening, so there's nothing to "get right". Just look at the documentation! The `string` property is declared like this:

> `@property(copy) id string`

That means exactly what you're seeing: when you set it, it takes an immutable copy. This is deliberate: if it were not so, then the string could be mutated behind the layer's back, which would throw everything off. Indeed, if your own classes have any string properties, they should work the same way.

If you need to change the string, just set the `string` property again. If you need to change the string based on its current value, fetch the `string`, make a `mutableCopy`, change it, and set it - just as with *any* of the immutable / mutable class cluster pairs in Foundation.

The *name* of the class is irrelevant, as I presume you realize: it's a class cluster, so private names like NSConcreteMutableAttributedString (instead of NSMutableString) are none of your business. You should never use the class name as a way of testing whether a mutable Foundation class instance is mutable, in any case: just ask the object whether it responds to a mutable method.

Comment: And see my discussion here: http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch10.html#_immutable_and_mutable

Comment: I just have to change my string very very often. And so I have to create a new NSMutableAttributedString again and again. I hoped that I can lessen the impact of object creation on performance.

Comment: Oh flapdoodle. There's no "performance" issue here. Don't optimize prematurely. Worry about things worth worrying about.

Comment: Or if you're really worried, keep the mutable string in your own world. That's the proper behavior in any case (model - view - controller: the layer is view, so you should be keeping the data off in the model world, separately). So now you can just keep changing your own mutable string and keep setting the layer's `string` from it, without ever having to fetch it.

Comment: Okay thank you I see that. Mabye I might ask you something else on that topic: I've set a negative kerning on my CATextLayer with these attributed strings (-2.0f). But now the rightmost letter is clipped a little (I've got it right justified). Do you have an idea what I could do there?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! If you have another question, ask a new question! You get more reputation points and you provide a chance for people to answer properly.

Comment: Nevermind I found out I can apply kerning to a certain range of letters (in case somebody else might read this)